# Tracking form submission

Tags: javascript

I'm developing tracking script which tracks some events (page view, link click, custom, ...) and sends them to API. Problem is I'm little bit stuck with form submission. So far I have following...

At first I add event listeners to every form on page:

```
const forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener("submit", trackFormSubmit);
  }
}
```

And then **trackFormSubmit** function:

```
const trackFormSubmit = function(evt) {
  if (evt.preventDefault) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  const form = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  const formElements = form.elements;

  // parse form data payload here, not important to show
  const event = {
    ...
  };

  Helper.sendEvent(event)
    .then(() => {
      form.submit();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      form.submit();
    });
};
```

`Helper.sendEvent` function sends the event to the API. This solution works well for non-SPA websites, however it's not working great for SPA. I've tested it in React where I had a form using Redux Form library - the form submission was successfully tracked but I've received console error:

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

The `evt.preventDefault()` doesn't work as expected in this case. Have someone an idea how this can be implemented?

**Well I have to clarify the above statement:** `evt.preventDefault` is called by Redux Form library so you have to handle `onSubmit` by your function (send data somewhere + redirect). I guess it's same in other Single-Page-Apps, there's no `action` where the user is sent ... default form behaviour is prevented initially.

Comment: Why do you need `preventDefault` there at all? If all you want is just tracking submission, `preventDefault` is unnecessary.

Comment: @hindmost when you have non-SPA website, you'll be likely redirected to another page and without `preventDefault` it's not guaranteed that the event submission will be executed, or am I wrong? I've tried to send event in `setInterval` with 500ms delay and it was not executed.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I would listen for the submit event on the document itself. That way you can also catch dynamically created forms. You could have a React tracking component that wraps your entire application.

Comment: @hindmost well, I discovered I really don't need `preventDefault`. I've set the `setTimeout` to my api response and it works ... javascript never stops surprising me :) I thought the api call will be killed. Thanks ;)

Comment: @hindmost heh, my bad ... it throws an error even if it successfully writes the event to db - `TypeError: Failed to fetch` :-D damn (trying to solve non single page apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking value of `event.isDefaultPrevented` solved the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your ES6 arrow function `trackFormSubmit` is defined before your `for` loop that sets the event listener to every form. This could cause the code to work but without listening to the form submit.

Here is an example of setting up the event listener for every form in the document and handling their submit.

```
const trackFormSubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target || event.srcElement;
  const formElements = form.elements;  
  alert(`Form ${event.target.name} was submited.`);
};


const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
forms.forEach(f=>{
  f.addEventListener("submit",trackFormSubmit);
});
```

Here is a fiddle so you can view how this code works:

https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/fgL5owdj/

Also, I changed the way of setting the event listeners to a `forEach` way. Which is a lot more readable.

Hope this gives you at least an idea of how it would work.

Comment: I don't have a problem witch catching form submission event

Comment: But with preventing default form submission. I posted an example of a working event listener preventing every default form submission.

Comment: It's already prevented in Redux Form for example so you are not redirected to some page after submission and you have to handle this on your own in `onSubmit` code. Your code is not different in any important part, I have it almost same. I've got also `trackFormSubmit` defined first.